# Wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)

Tags: ruby

I am currently working on a small school project (Ruby) but I am getting this error (Wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)) that makes me wanna flip a table. :(

This is the code that I am trying to get to work:

```
puts "How much does the product cost?"
price = gets.to_f.round

puts "How much money will you give for it?"
money = gets.to_f

change = calculate_change(price, money)
```

I use that to get the user input, round the first to a fixnum and then the second one to a float. This is how my calculate_change method looks like:

```
def calculate_change(price, money)
    return money - price
end
```

Comment: This code works for me. Are you sure you declare calculate_change before you try to call it?

Comment: Holy cow, why the hell didn't I do that. Thank you. XD

Comment: Will do, lesson learned, thanks.

Comment: Also, just a point of style, `return` is assumed here in Ruby. You could just put `money - price` since that returns the answer and a method will return the last thing it evaluates. (I know there's a better way of saying that...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per @hirolau's comment, you need to make sure you declare `calculate_change()` before the call to it.

```
def calculate_change(price, money)
    money - price                    # return is optional in Ruby!
end

puts "How much does the product cost?"
price = gets.to_f.round

puts "How much money will you give for it?"
money = gets.to_f

change = calculate_change(price, money)
```

Comment: Didn't know about that return thing, pretty nice I must say. Thanks :)

Comment: Why do you get "wrong number of arguments" instead of something like "no such function…"?

Comment: @sam I think the OP must have been using an older version of Ruby. With 2.2.0, I get `undefined method`.